# Best method for swapping rows in 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays, swap

I want to do this in C++ code:

- Initialize an array with 4 rows and 5 columns;
- Ask the user about two row numbers in the range 0 to 4;
- Swap the rows defined by the user in a 2D array.

Comment: OK? I want a lot of things. But generally I don't expect people on the internet to do them for me. Have you tried writing any code yet? Was there any particular problem? Also, did you try searching first? There are already equivalent questions and answers, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759399/swapping-two-rows-in-a-matrix and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930987/swapping-2-numbers-in-2-dimensional-array and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696705/swap-rows-or-columns-of-a-2d-array-in-o1-time-in-c

Comment: Your range will need to be 0 to 3 for the rows.  Row with index of 4 is outside the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following algorithm:

```
let arr be array
let a,b be row indices that are swapped
for each column index i
    swap arr[a][i] and arr[b][i]
```

However, if instead of a 2d array you were to use an array of row pointers, you could instead simply swap the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare an extra variable to temporarily hold each value as you swap it from row A to B.

Not sure what you mean by "best", is this in terms of speed or memory requirements?